# Testing multiple scenarios under one Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit

This is how I am doing my unit test in groovy.

```
public void testSomeMethod() {
  doSomething(1,2,3,4);      //this is first test
  doSomething(11,22,33,44);   //this is second test
}


private void doSomething(a, b, c, d) {
  assertEquals(a, actual)
    }
```

Basically I am calling doSomething 2 times with different values under same test.
It might not be a good way to test But I just want to try it out.

**So, the problem is, if the first test fails second does't get executed.**

**Is there a way I can force it to print fail message and move on to next one?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a good time for you to use [spock](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/), where you can do data driven testing and the second test will not be gated by the first one. You can get more flexibility like the one you have asked for and more.

Eventually, the test would look something like:

```
void "test something"(){
    when:
       def result = doSomething(a, b, c, d)

    then:
       result == expectedResult

    where:
       a   | b  | c  | d   || expectedResult
       1   | 2  | 3  | 4   || 100           
       11  | 22 | 33 | 44  || 1000
}

private doSomething(a, b, c, d){...}
```

You can find more details in spock framework documents and/or also have a look at [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user:2051952%20spock).

BTW, above test example can be over simplified to make it groovier. ;)

```
void "test something"(){
    expect:
       result == doSomething(a, b, c, d)

    where:
       a   | b  | c  | d   || result
       1   | 2  | 3  | 4   || 100           
       11  | 22 | 33 | 44  || 1000
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to show me this. I tried spock and I really like it. Mostly because its so readable and the format of the test helps organize the code very well.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the advice given to use Spock(great framework) you can also use [JUnit parameterized tests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) if you don't want to include additional dependencies.

Comment: I tried both and I found spock more readable so i am using it. But thanks a lot